# VSCode terminal shows incorrect python version and path, launching terminal from anaconda works perfectly

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-code, anaconda

I have been stuck on this one problem for hours now and believe I have tried everything outside of throwing my computer out of the window.

I have a virtual environment set up on Anaconda using python version 3.7 and Django version 2.1. If I activate this virtual environment from Anaconda everything works smoothly.

```
(movierecommender) bash-3.2$ python -V
Python 3.7.2
(movierecommender) bash-3.2$ python -m django --version
2.1.5
```

However when I try to activate the environment from a vscode terminal I get

```
(movierecommender) maxs-MBP:movies maxswann$ python -V
Python 2.7.10
(movierecommender) maxs-MBP:movies maxswann$ python -m django --version
/usr/bin/python: No module named django
```

I have `Python 3.7.2 64-bit ('movierecommender':conda)`
showing as my python interpreter in the bottom left of my vscode window yet still get the wrong python version

I thought this may be to do with the PYTHONPATH but have tried unsetting and resetting even though I should not have to worry about this in Anaconda as it automatically adds:
`"python.pythonPath":"/Users/maxswann/anaconda3/envs/movierecommender/bin/python"`
to a settings.json.vscode file

using:

```
python -c "import sys; print(sys.path)"
```

Anaconda-launched terminal

```
['', '/Users/maxswann/anaconda3/envs/movierecommender/lib/python37.zip', '/Users/maxswann/anaconda3/envs/movierecommender/lib/python3.7', '/Users/maxswann/anaconda3/envs/movierecommender/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload', '/Users/maxswann/anaconda3/envs/movierecommender/lib/python3.7/site-packages']
```

Vs Code terminal

```
['', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC']
```

As you can see it seems to be using the default mac OS python version.

Has anybody else had this problem before? I've been tearing hair out all day trying to fix this

Comment: Have you installed the Python extension for VSCode? It makes it much easier to manage things like this.

Comment: I also got this issue just now, do you finally able to solve this?

Comment: Still haven't figured this out and just gave up on using the vscode terminal. Hoping someone could shine some light on this.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I have been facing the exact same problem. Finally found a workaround from a forum (https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/issues/4434#issuecomment-466600591)

As long as you ADD some stuff to configuration, `terminal.integrated.env.osx`, the content will be appended to `PATH` after shell initialization(source bash_profile or zshrc). In my Mojave, I simply add following empty entry to my user configuration:

```
"terminal.integrated.env.osx": {
        "PATH": ""
}
```

Then the `$PATH` will be the same as the external terminal.

Comment: I checked out the forum post and this seems to be the exact same issue. Could you clarify further where that code should be pasted? You say "in my Mojave" but i'm not entirely sure what you mean by that. If this works I'll mark this as solved, thanks

Comment: You should paste it in settings.json file for your user. You can find it in Preferences -> Settings -> User Preferences tab. Just type settings, you will find an option to `Edit in settings.json`. Or the file is located at `~/Library/Application Support/Code/User/settings.json`.

Comment: on Windows it's in `C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\settings.json`

Answer (score 36):

The officially accepted answer by @Samuel was the correct answer at the time.

But VS Code has now provided a [better way to handle it](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_36#_launch-terminals-with-clean-environments).

In short, open up your user settings and add this line of code:

```
    "terminal.integrated.inheritEnv": false,
```

This prevents stomping over whatever Python environment manager you are using (eg, venv, conda, etc).

Comment: Facing same issue in windows and Unfortunately This does not work for windows :(

Comment: Worked for me on MacOS, thanks! As a note VS code highlights this initially when a condo environment is detected.

Comment: @DragonZoned I have a Mac, so I cannot say.  However, I have colleagues with Windows machines that have a *lot* more trouble on VS Code than I do.  That seems strange (VS Code is a MS product, after all).

But my guess is this: this is not a problem with VS Code, but with Python.  It is far easier to run Python on Windows these days than 5 - 10 years ago, but it is still not as graceful or easy as it is on Linux/Mac.  :(

Comment: A similar issue on non-Anaconda machines (e.g. Homebrew) where the VS Code terminal uses a different Python version than the MacOS Terminal cannot be solved by this. But it can be solved by @Samuel's solution.

Comment: where to paste above line ?

Answer (score 3):

For Windows users:

First if you haven't done already, set VS code (the editor, not its terminal) to the desired Python environment, using `Ctrl+Shift+P --> Python: Select interpreter`.

Then, Change VS code's default terminal from Powershell to CMD. This is what worked for me at least.

Answer (score 2):

**Windows Solution:**

If anyone in the future ends up scratching their heads over this particular problem, I’ve found another culprit, which blocked me for this problem on Windows:

[image: Showcase of setting]
Terminal>Integrated>Env: Enable Persistent Sessions

I suspect what happens is that after you update system paths, VScode caches the old path in the terminal and persists it. In this case it persists the old python path rather than the new conda one.

Toggling this option off and restarting VSCode clears that cache, and the new path is loaded in. You can also toggle the option back on after you’re done.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into the same problem. Try switching out of the powershell terminal to the windows terminal. Then restart. It should restart with the anaconda terminal. If that does not work you could:

First change the default terminal from within Visual Code to the CMD terminal instead of Powershell. Add the following code to a batch file.

```
call "c:\path\to\anaconda3\Scripts\activate"
```

Then I named the batch file and saved it to my root directory. In my case `snake.bat`. Now when I launch my CMD terminal I just type `c:\snake.bat` and the CMD prompt changes into an Anaconda prompt.

Comment: I didn't catch that

Comment: For me, just switchig the VS code default terminal from Powershell to CMD worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For me simply changing the Python interpreter inside VS Code worked. You still can take advantage of Pyenvs installations there: View -> Command Palette -> Select Python Interpreter

Answer (score -1):

I ran this script. Now python3 is running from virtual env. [Windows 10]

```
pip3 install virtualenv
virtualenv env
call ".\env\Scripts\activate.bat"
set requirements="./Requirements.txt"
pip3 install -r %requirements%
python
```