# How can i upgrade python in VSCode terminal?

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, visual-studio-code, terminal

So i have installed both python 2.x and 3.x on my PC and have also selected 3.x as my default python interpreter in VSCode. So, as expected whenever i use python code runner extension it uses 3.x as it's base but whenever i try to use VSCode terminal instead it uses 2.x python. How can i change that to 3.x?

I tried using:

```
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

but i don't think that works in VSCode. Is there any fix or am i stuck with 2.x in terminal?

Comment: There is no such thing as "VSCode terminal". The terminal accessible via VSCode is your ""normal"" computer terminal. You should probably be using the `python3` command instead of `python`.

Comment: fix your system path.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VSCode terminal shows incorrect python version and path, launching terminal from anaconda works perfectly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54582361/vscode-terminal-shows-incorrect-python-version-and-path-launching-terminal-from)

Answer (score -1):

### Select interpreter

Select python interpreter to the python version you want by pressing

- `F1`
- select interpreter
- select your interpreter you want

This should use the Python3 interpreter

### Run python3 instead of python

Run python in terminal by calling `python3` instead of `python`

Comment: This changes the interpreter used by the runner extension, it has no effect whatsoever on the terminal.